# Android Emulator is Blank

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a mid 2013 Macbook Air (so I should have the resources to make the emulator work) and I'm trying to get the Android Emulator working. It's been half an hour and the color pinwheel continues to spin.  In the meantime I looked up and downloaded Andy and BlueStacks Android emulators but Andy was nothing more than a clock with no buttons and BlueStacks, while it had a number of options there was nothing that seemed evident that I could get 'Hello World' running from the basic tutorial.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

I want to progress but I'm stuck. Thanks.

Comment: I'm also running 2013 Air 10.10.4 Yosemite w/HAXM - I get no pinwheel, I just created a Galaxy Nexus x86 API 22 in a few minutes, same for an ARM version. Which version of OS are you running / have you re-downloaded the emulator images (just in case) / checked that your harddrive/SSD isn't failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start an emulator you should "Store a snapshot for faster performance" in the Android Virtual Device (AVD) configuration or the emulator won't start at all.  After too much time troubleshooting, it was as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com). They have a great android emulator that can spin up vms for different phones. Its free for personal use and easy to use. The VM image is download directly from their server so when it gets corrupted you can delete it and add it again.

It is also recognized by Eclipse and Android Studio.

There should be two downloads, one that includes Oracle VM and one that doesn't. I recommend the one that does so you do not need to install Oracle VM by its self.

If that doesn't work post a comment and ill see what I can do.

Comment: Ok I'm going to download with you right now and see.

Comment: I'm trying to get past the very basics on the Genymotion website as the directions to download the plugin are file -> settings -> plugins -> browse repositories and there is no 'settings' option just 'import settings', 'export settings' and 'other settings'. 'other settings' has a 'configure plugins' option. When I click that option nothing happens.  Where am I going wrong? I'm getting pretty frustrated.

Comment: Is the plugin for Eclipse? If it is then it is not necessary. You can start the emulator for the device you want and then run the project in your IDE. It should ask you which device that you want to use. At that point pick the Genymotion IDE that was just started.

Comment: It's for Android Studio. I just started with Android/Java so I'm pretty clueless . . . deviations from details will generally leave me lost at this time.

Comment: Ah ok. Were you able to pick a device and start the emulator? Also were the settings that you were talking about in Genymotion? If you have not already seen the install page, it can be found [here](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide#getting-started)

Comment: No. The directions here https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download don't matchup correctly with my UI options. I can't figure the path they want me to take to do it.

Comment: Yeah don't worry about the stuff with Android Studio. There should be a download button that says "Get Genymotion" that looks like this http://puu.sh/iLsb1/a08a433dca.png. Once you have that downloaded open the dmg and run it. It then should ask you to log into the application with the account you just made with them. After you log in you should be at a page that looks like this http://puu.sh/iLsku/404769a86c.png. At that point click add and and select the device. Then click on the added device to start the emulator.

Comment: I open it and I get a shell. What do I do with that? Are you available for chat?

Answer (score 1):

try restarting your computer..

Comment: Been there and done that. 15 minutes have passed since the last restart and the pinwheel is still going.